# array to json in php

Tags: php

I want to create bootstrap typeahead.

Here is print of my array in php.

```
debug($array);
//print $array =>
 array(
  4 => string 'Michelle' (length=8)
  6 => string 'Freya' (length=5)
  9 => string 'Ivana' (length=5)
  14 => string 'Stephanie' (length=9)
 );
```

I need to get some thing like this:

```
['Michelle', 'Freya', 'Ivana', 'Stephanie']
```

Comment: Just make 
$myAwesomeArray = array('Michelle','Freya','Ivana','Stephanie');

Is that what you want?

Comment: Please give more context on what you're trying to do. Arrays are *always* indexed, whether numerically or by strings. You cannot "remove numbers".

Comment: `$yourstring = json_encode(array_values($yourarray));`

Comment: Thank you var_dump(json_encode(array_values($users)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_values http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
$arrayWithoutCustomIndexes = array_values($array);
```